# How to Store an ObjectId in an HttpSession and Retrieve it? (MonoDB Java Driver)

Tags: java, mongodb, debugging, nullpointerexception, mongodb-java

I am trying to store an `ObjectId` as an `HttpSession` attribute, then retrieve it later on in the program. However, the program is producing a `NullPointerException` when trying to retrieve `new ObjectId((String)session.getAttribute("id"))`

This is the code for storing the ObjectId:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("id", collection.find(eq("email", email)).first().getObjectId("_id").toHexString());
session.setAttribute("user_type", userType);
```

This is the code for retrieving the ObjectId:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
ObjectId id = new ObjectId((String)session.getAttribute("id"));
```

Interestingly, the following code does not produce a `NullPointerException:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
System.out.println(session.getAttribute("id").toString());
```

From this, it seems that the `ObjectId` did indeed get stored as an attribute in the HttpSession, but for some reason a `NullPointerException` is created when trying to retrieve it in the way that I did.

How would I retrieve the `ObjectId` in a way that does not produce this exception?

Comment: Have you ever tried `ObjectId id = new ObjectId();` and then `ObjectId id = ObjectId.get(session.getAttribute("id"));` ?

Comment: @CKWong I can't find a method in the Mongo Java Driver API for `ObjectId` called `get ` that would accept `session.getAttribute("id")` such as `ObjectId.get(session.getAttribute("id"))`

Comment: Actually why you want to get the session to Java MongoDB Client instance instead of a database connection / data source?

Answer (score 0):

This `NPE` can occur if your `session` is null or if your `session.getAttribute("id")` returns `null`.

You will have to verify whether any of these are null and then apply some correction.

I think you can try the following approach to avoid the `NPE`.

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
if(session == null){
  System.println("session is null");
}else{
  Object _id = session.getAttribute("id");
  ObjectId id = _id != null ? new ObjectId((String)_id) : _id;
}
```

Or you can try some debugger in your IDE to identify the issue exactly.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I dug around further after your answer and found out that the session id sometimes changes between servlets, so it seems like the session doesn't persist between requests. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: This seems unlikely that servlets in the same app will have different session ids. There might be session timeout or session is invalidated/reset somewhere in your code such that a new session is started and you lose the data from the previous session.